# .MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**Getting Error For the Following Code**

```
  package jdbcdrive;

import java.sql.*;
public class Lpt {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lpt?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","2664");

        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sys.lpt");

        while(rs.next()) {

            System.out.println(rs.getInt("BatchName")+" "+rs.getString("StudentName")+" "+rs.getString("StudentName")+" "+rs.getString("studentMobileNo")+" "+rs.getString("Address"));
        }

    }

}
```

The Output Error I'm getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Comment: This issue mostly occured when mysql service is not started. start mysql service and start connection

Comment: Started in Services and its running too but getting the same error

Comment: ok try one more thing remove port number make it as jdbc:mysql://localhost/

Comment: thanks Engr,But the result is same error

Comment: follow this i hope this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your connection String:

```
"useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"
```

it worked for me

Comment: I already had my connection string (`spring.datasource.url`) quite close to that, except for the timezone which shouldn't matter. What solved it for me was to append `&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` to the connection string! hope this helps someone